# What is the benefit of async/await if only one thread is available?

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

I am a C++ developer new to the await/async paradigm and my understanding doesn't align with my expectation what it does. Lets take a look at the following code:

```js
fs.readFile(fileName, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
   console.log("open");
})
```

From my understanding, `fs.readFile` is asynchronous to avoid blocking. So far so good, but all tutorials mention explicetely there is only **1** thread. So how can an I/O operation be executed asynchronously, and e.g. another asynchronous function be executed if there is only **1** thread?

Let's assume (only for this example) the underlying C function `open` blocks for 30 seconds. Wouldn't that block the entire execution of other "asynchronous" functions as well? But that doesn't seem to be the case. So how many threads are **really** involved when executing asynchronous code?

My expectation would be, that it behaves like a state machine. That means, conceptually there is only 1 thread involved, but technically more than one. Is that correct?

Disclaimer: I am aware of "parallelism != concurrent".

Comment: Heard about EventLoop?

Comment: Yes, would the event loop hang as well if `open()` would block?

Comment: This will help you understand I think. https://heynode.com/tutorial/explore-io-callbacks-phase-nodejs-event-loop

Comment: The "1" thread part doesn't really matter. Step tasking could be whats really at play but its happens so tightly and fast that it appears "parallel".

Comment: @GetSet Makes sense, it sounds like Python and the GIL.

Comment: I'd say it depends on what you think of *only 1 thread*. Especially does OS thread doing job for you consider single thread? There is also non-blocking IOs and some are asynchronous  by nature (like network).

Comment: async/await came from c#

Answer (score 2):

I/O will run in different threads, and most I/O is non-blocking.

When people say node.js is 1 thread, it means that only 1 part of your javascript will be executed at any given time. But if you are reading a file from disk, that is slow enough that there's enough time for javascript to schedule other code to run while javascript waits for the read to complete.

Comment: Thanks! It drove me nuts, you just confirmed what I always expected, but often JS devs don't get me when I ask "how many threads are **really** involved?" So technically it works like similarly like Python and the GIL! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you have any reference or background information on your statement? Just to understand it deeper

Comment: Sorry, I can't think of a hard reference at the moment.

Comment: No problem! You helped a lot!